# Choppy animation of popViewControllerAnimated: from alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, uialertview, popviewcontrolleranimated

I'm having problem with the animation in the method `popViewControllerAnimated:` when it's done inside the `UIalertView` delegate method `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` It's choppy and to fast (using Xcode 7.3.1). Can anyone understand why?

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        // animation of popViewControllerAnimated: is not working correctly
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that this code works without problems:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        // code is running om main thread
        if ([[NSThread currentThread]isMainThread])  {
            // still - by using GCD and go to main thread, the animation works!!
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if(buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        // no problem with animation when done in alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

I know that the `UIAlertView` has been deprecated for a while, can it be because of that? This code has been untouched in the app since 2012 and recently started to behave strange.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with `willDismissWithButtonIndex` instead of `didDismissWithButtonIndex`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

for me this work ok!, I hope this helps you

Comment: Yes, thanks it works :) As well as `clickedButtonAtIndex:`as I wrote in the question. But I'm still puzzled about what's the problem with `didDismissWithButtonIndex:`....